# How do I refresh TinyMCE for the code that I add with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to insert  code for flash to TinyMCE with JavaScript. If I insert the same code using HTML menu of TinyMCE, it automatically add flash icon to the editor. But if I insert the code using JavaScript, the actual code is inserted but it shows nothing on the screen.

One trick I found is toggle TinyMCE to normal textarea and back to TinyMCE. Then, it shows the flash icon. Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: The toggling trick has a big glitch. It flickers the editor. I found another way. At first, I used mceInsertContent which didn't repaint the editor. But mceInsertRawHTML works as I expect.

Comment: Sam, you totally made my day!!

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code...**

```
var content=tinyMCE.get('comment').getContent()+"ur flash content";
tinyMCE.get('comment').setContent(content);
```

---

Since i dont know about flash. but using this way u can insert into tinymce

Answer (score 1):

Have u tried using:mceRepaint ?

http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Commands

Comment: I've already tried that and it didn't work. Strange... Thanks for your suggestion, though.